# What is the difference between a culture and a civilization?

Tags: cultural-history, historiography, civilizations

This is my first question on this site. So, I just hope I would be helped here.

As used by historians, what is the difference between a 'civilization' and a 'culture'?

I used Google to find some logical answers but couldn't find anything satisfactory.

Comment: Can you expand your question, explaining what part of the wiki entries for [culture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Culture) and [civilization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Civilization) you aren't satisfied with?

Comment: Edited to clarify that you didn't want a general English Language question, and removed the request for opinions (which is by definition off-topic here). If you don't like the changes, feel free to revert them.

Comment: I need some main points to differentiate between them. Because, I would like to put the remarks in examination. I want to collect some ideas for examination because 'civilization' is our subject in Pakistan.

Comment: I am as sick as a parrot because of "civilization" its concepts, and evolution! I looked up it on Google but I didn't find anything satisfactory. Now, I am looking for help over here.

Comment: Using a linguistic aproach, I would say that a civilization is a culture with an army.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A civilization is a culture of a certain scale and complexity. All civilizations are cultures, but only a small subset of cultures are civilizations.

As [the Wikipedia article on civilization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Civilization) puts it:

> Historically, a civilization was a so-called "advanced" culture in
>   contrast to more supposedly primitive cultures... In this
>   broad sense, a civilization contrasts with non-centralized tribal
>   societies, including the cultures of nomadic pastoralists, egalitarian
>   horticultural subsistence neolithic societies or hunter-gatherers... Civilizations are organized in densely populated
>   settlements divided into hierarchical social classes with a ruling
>   elite and subordinate urban and rural populations, which engage in
>   intensive agriculture, mining, small-scale manufacture and trade.

All human populations participate in one or more cultural groups regardless of whether they are part of a civilization.

Answer (score 3):

Culture is a more general notion. "Civilization is characterized by  urban development, social stratification, symbolic communication etc. (see Wikipedia).
So we can speak of a Paleolitic culture, for example but not a civilization.